# Variable iconUrl in Leaflet, use GEOJson property voor iconUrl definition (Leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, geojson, icon, url

My script is as follows:

```
function clickFeature(e, feature) {
  var layer = e.target;
  var string = new feature.properties.categorie;
  var bigIcon = new BigIcon({iconSize: [24, 40], iconUrl: +string+'.png'});
  layer.setIcon(layer.options.icon == smallIcon ? bigIcon : smallIcon);
}

var jsonLaag1 = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
  filter: categorie1,
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: smallIcon
    });
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature,

});

function categorie1(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.categorie == '1') return true
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    'mouseover': clickFeature
  })
  layer.on({
    'mouseout': clickFeature
  })
}
```

It returns `feature is undefined` in the console
Somewhere further in my script I just can filter with the value of categorie (category in dutch) with the same definition. What goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to your `function clickFeature(e, feature) {...}` function is always `undefined`. This happens because Leaflet event handler functions are expected to receive just one parameter (the event).

Do not expect computer code to automagically pass around the values that you need.

Internally, the [leaflet code for `L.Evented.fire()`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/d8dd2f0a40aabb38956fea9b8fde4092191ca179/src/core/Events.js#L190) calls the handler function with just the given context (if set) and one argument via [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

There are several approaches to a correct implementation.

---

One approach is to use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) of the GeoJSON feature:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on('mouseover mouseout': function(ev) {
      clickFeature(ev, feature);
  });
}
```

And since this is the only appearance of a call to `clickFeature`, that should be refactored as well.

---

Another approach is to store the needed data in the leaflet layer, which the event handler can access:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.featureCategory = feature.category;
  layer.on('mouseover mouseout', clickFeature)
}

function clickFeature(e, feature) {
  var layer = e.target;
  var category = layer.featureCategory;
  // etc
}
```